# How to kill a process in Java, given a specific PID

Tags: java, windows

How do I kill a specific process from Java code on Windows, if I have the specific PID.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know any other solution, apart from executing a specific `Windows` command like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID 827");`

Comment: add /F flag so that it kills SYSTEM processes too.

Comment: As I remember, taskkill.exe is only available on Windows XP Professional and later (not in the Home Edition). You might consider shipping the code with something like pskill, just in case: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx

Comment: @Hypnos Shipping your app with pskill is dangerous because many virus scanners detect pskill as "dangerous application" for an unknown reason.

Comment: add /T flag so that if the process is a 16 bit and launched into the ntvdm wow system, that too will be killed. Otherwise it might still run even though the launching script has been killed.

Answer (score 2):

With `Java 9`, we can use [ProcessHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html):

```
ProcessHandle.of(11395).ifPresent(ProcessHandle::destroy);
```

where `11395` is the `pid` of the process you're interested in killing.

This:

- First creates an `Optional<ProcessHandle>` from the given `pid`
- And if this `ProcessHandle` is present, kills the process using `destroy`.

No import necessary as `ProcessHandle` is part of `java.lang`.

To force-kill the process, one might prefer `ProcessHandle::destroyForcibly` to `ProcessHandle::destroy`.