# How interrupt a Linux proccess using Java

Tags: java, linux, process, interrupt

I have a process generator that make some processes working in linux (this code is by java) but during these processes working I want to make some interrupt to change the process config.

If I use an spooling method , It have too many overflow So I want to use another method to make some interrupts into other processes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633678/how-to-kill-a-process-in-java-given-a-specific-pid check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the answer linked by @Vlad is for Windows, and this question is for linux, here's an answer to that. Linux [uses signals to interrupt processes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1332), and you can use `kill` to send a signal:

```
// shut down process with id 123 (can be ignored by the process)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill 123");
// shut down process with id 123 (can not be ignored by the process)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 123");
```

with kill, you can also send other signals as told in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) (and it doesn't have to be a killing signal). By default, kill will send a `SIGTERM` signal, which tells the process to terminate, but it can be ignored. If you want the process to terminate without the possibility for ignore, `SIGKILL` can be used. In the code above, first call uses SIGTERM, the latter one SIGKILL. You can also be explicit about it:

```
// shut down process with id 123 (can be ignored by the process)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -SIGTERM 123");
// shut down process with id 123 (can not be ignored by the process)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -SIGKILL 123");
```

If you want to operate with name of the target program instead of process id, there's also `killall` which will accept the name as a parameter. As the name implies, that would kill all processes that match. Example:

```
// shuts down all firefox processes (can not be ignored)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall -SIGKILL firefox");
```

Answer (score 1):

To kill the process get the pid of that process using the below command
**`ps -ef | grep 'process name'`**
use the pid to kill the process where pid is 16804
Ex :

```
[root@localhost content]# ps -ef | grep tomcat
root     16804     1  0 Apr09 ?        00:00:42 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local2/tomcat66/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -/usr/local2/tomcat66/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local2/tomcat66 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local2/tomcat66 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local2/tomcat66/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Then in java use the command

```
1. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -15 16804"); // where -15 is SIGTERM 
or
2. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -9 16804"); // where -9 is SIGKILL
```

Check this for various [Killing processes](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/shell/jobz5.html) and this for [killing signals](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Sending_signal_to_Processes)